Azure Identity: how to authenticate from the browser (popup or redirect mode) when the site is viewed from a Teams tab?
I created an SPFx Web part for SharePoint Online, in Typescript.
What I want to achieve is to consumme an Azure OpenAI instance from the browser, under the identity of the currently logged-in user.
I included the following packages in my SPFx solution:

@azure/identity 4.4.1
@azure/openai 2.0.0-beta.1

To authenticate against Azure, I registered an Azure App with delegated permissions to OpenAI.
I then use the following code:
const credentials = new InteractiveBrowserCredential({
        tenantId: <tenantId>,
        clientId: <clientId>,
        redirectUri: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname,
        loginStyle: "redirect", // I also tried: "popup",
        loginHint: <userName>,
      });
const azureADTokenProvider = getBearerTokenProvider(credentials, "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default");
this.m_client = new AzureOpenAI({
        azureADTokenProvider,
        baseURL: <openAIAPIBaseUrl>,
        apiVersion: <openAIAPIVersion>,
        deployment: <openAIAPIDeployment>
      });

Everything works great!... if I navigate the SharePoint site, where the SPFx Web part is deployed, from a standard brower.
But my goal however is to host the SharePoint site in a Teams tab: users will navigate the site from the Teams application.
And here is the problem: the above authentication code, involving InteractiveBrowserCredential can either leverages a popup or redirections.

With the popup mode, it fails with error popup_window_error: Error opening popup window. This can happen if you are using IE or if popups are blocked in the browser. as Teams does not allow popups.

With the redirect mode, it also fails. The error reads: redirect_in_iframe: Redirects are not supported for iframed or brokered applications. Please ensure you are using MSAL.js in a top frame of the window if using the redirect APIs, or use the popup APIs. This time, it's because of the X-Frame-Options header set to DENY by the login page sent by Microsoft.


How can I achieve silent authentication from my WPFx Web part when the site is rendered in a Teams tab?

You'd have to break out of the iframe, and open the authentication URL in the top window instance ... whether Teams tabs actually allow you to do this, I couldn't tell you though.

Why can't you use SSO where the user's Teams login credentials are used to authenticate the user?

@GauravMantri would you have a code sample for that? The goal is to get an azureADTokenProvider object I could use as a parameter for new AzureOpenAI.

Please have look into this Sample1.https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs
2.https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-nested-auth/nodejs
